# Algorithms graphics tools

Tags: algorithms, data-structure

What tools are most useful for creating algorithm and data structure graphics for teaching? I am specifically seeking to have a voice over the graphics running for an algorithm.

For example, when I'm trying to teach the KMP algorithm (Knuth–Morris–Pratt) or Iterative PostOrder traversal, I need many figures representing many states and DS as well showing transition states succinctly. I've been using power point but it seems to require too much effort and provide less flexibility.

Freeware (gratis) is preferred, but I'm open to paid options as well (cheaper is better).

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but it might be helpful to include some images of the graphics you currently use. Would you mind elaborating on what exactly you dislike about powerpoint, and specific features you'd like to see in an alternative?

Comment: A google search for "Algorithm Visualization" will turn up quite a lot, actually. It has been an active research topic since at least 1980. Any programming language with a decent graphics library should be sufficient using Model-View-Controller logic.

Comment: For sort and search, I use cards (paper computer), and get the students do do the algorithms. It may work for other algorithms. Also for these algorithms are dancers (search in the inter-web). I wonder if we could do this for Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm.

Comment: I don't dislike anything about power point. (It just a little time consuming and since I only do them in my free time, could be just that I need to become more proficient).  So I was only wondering if professionals use anything more that power point. I just thought may be powerful tools might be available now. I saw some cool animations in cs.usfca.edu.